# SQL JSON Column (IgnoreCase)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, json, mysql-json

I have a SQL column in JSON Format which looks like `data->'$.name'` and I wanted to ask if it's possible to make an Ignore Case to this column like
`UPPER(data->'$.name')`.

Example:
`select * from TYPE_hugo_DATA WHERE UPPER(data->'$.name') = UPPER('hugo');`

Comment: Are you using Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you make the equals on the raw json value, which contains the quotes(`"`).

If you want to retrieve the json value without the quotes you can either do `->>` is the short syntax for the `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT())`:

```
select * from TYPE_hugo_DATA WHERE UPPER(data->>'$.name') = UPPER('hugo');
```

or

```
select * from TYPE_hugo_DATA WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.name')) = UPPER('hugo');
```